# Change event "touch to beam" using NFC

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have one application that makes communication to other application using NFC beam. The beam NFC works. I just want that when I active the NFC, the screen doesn't resize, I just want a small vibration to confirm the transfer of data. Is possible this ideia? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to write your own Android Beam implementation and then turn off Android Beam. This is likely way more work then you want. The Android Beam feature is built into the system itself so you cannot change nearly all aspects of it on people's phones currently.

This includes changing the text.